# VB.NET: Get class name of a instance

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, class, instance

Is there a way to get the instance's class name with VB.NET?

Answer (score 23):

Try the following

```
Dim name = Me.GetType().Name
```

Or for any instance

```
Dim name = theObject.GetType().Name
```

Comment: how would you do this at the shared level? supporting subclasses as well?

Answer (score 22):

```
Dim type As Type = yourObject.GetType()
Dim typeName As String = type.FullName
```

Full name will get you the fully qualified name of the Type, including the namespace of the Type.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_members(v=VS.71).aspx) for more information on what is available with `Type`.

Comment: how would you do this at the shared level with subclasses?

Answer (score 1):

This could be better when you are using asp.net website class not object.

```
Dim ClassName as string = Me.GetType().BaseType.FullName
```

OR

when you are using desktop app.

```
Dim ClassName as string = Me.GetType().Name
```

Comment: Me.GetType().BaseType.FullName doesn't get me the class name (for a class I coded).  It simply returns "System.Object".  But me.GetType().Name does return the name of my class.

Answer (score 1):

Using Reflection, you could do the following...

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()
```

I use the following when logging trace info.  This gives you the Class name, with all Namespaces and current Method name.

```
$"{System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()}.{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}"
```